# using curve gemetry /bevel/object

Tags: bevel

I will change the curly beziercurve into a solid rectangel schape 20mm on5mm.

To obtain a correct size on the beziercurve I have to make the section approchemately 5 times bigger.
[image]

Is there a straight relation bewtween section and curve possible?

Is there an other way to shape the curve exactly ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You likely have a smaller scale on your curve object, select it and clear the scale with Alt+S and it should then match the scale of your rectangle bevel object.

Alternatively, in Object Mode you can scale your curve object until it matches the rectangle bevel object's size, then do Ctrl+A > Apply Scale. From that point you can adjust the bevel object's size and it will match your curve.